# prelink-rtld: command not found

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, prelink

Getting Prelink-rtld: command not found error, when trying to build my project using yocto. 
**Complete error**:

```
work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.12.2-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/g-ir-scanner-lddwrapper: line 2: prelink-rtld: command not found

| ==6485==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.

| If the above error message is about missing .so libraries, then setting up GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH in the recipe should help.

| (typically like this: GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH="${B}/something/.libs" )
```

Tried adding DEPENDS += "prelink"

But this didn't solve the problem.

Started getting this error after enablink gcc-sanitizer.
i.e

```
+DEPENDS += "gcc-sanitizers"
+CFLAGS += "-fsanitize=address"
+CPPFLAGS += "-fsanitize=address"
+LDFLAGS += "-fsanitize=address"
```

in gstreamer1.0_1.12.2.bbappend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the native prelink version, because it is executed at build time.
Try using

```
DEPENDS += "prelink-native"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply MofX, this resolved prelinik-rtld issue,
However i am getting another error now:


    | ==13998==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.
    | If the above error message is about missing .so libraries, then setting up GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH in the recipe should help.
    | (typically like this: GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH="${B}/something/.libs" )